# Convert ###-###-#### phone number as a string instead of math operation

Tags: sql-server, excel, varchar, phone-number

I have phone number as `###-###-####` in my SQL table. When I export it to CSV file. It shows as turns into a value of the match operation, ie, treating `-` as a subtract sign.

Also, as an alternative, I can convert `###-###-####` as `##########`, ie, removing `-` how to do that in select query.

Thanks

I tried to cast (phone as `varchar`) but that didn't help.

Comment: CSV files don't do math.  Are you opening the CSV file in Excel?

Comment: CSV files don't have a concept of mathematical operators.  Your problem is related to how you're opening / reading it.  If you did do the conversion, and the phone number started with a 0, whatever you're doing to open the file would likely lose the leading zero.  Fix the actual problem, not the superficial symptom.  *(For example, import the csv file in such a way that the column is correctly treated as a string.)*

Comment: For that matter, CSV files don't have a concept of *numbers*; it's a stringly-typed format.  The actual question here seems to be “How do I force Excel to treat a particular column as text when I open a CSV filet?”

Comment: @FRANKBALL Yes I am opening in Excel.

Comment: @jarlh im doing in dermio so i guess SQL server.

Comment: As others explained, CSV files are just strings. In Excel you can change the style of a column to text so it isn't treated as a formula. Or, you can export your CSV file using text qualifiers (typically `"`) to tell any program that the field is a text, not a number

Comment: @CurlyShaan in SQL Server you can easily export data into Excel files directly using SSIS or the Export Data wizard. That wizard creates an SSIS package that can be reused

Comment: @CurlyShaan How do you export the file? Any method you use to export the CSV file from SQL Server should have a way to add text qualifiers.

Comment: Hi, all I am obviously not an expert and I use GUI of dermio to export the file as a CSV ( not excel format available ) and I am honestly not sure what SQL but I am sure it is not Oracle. I am not sure to say my DBMS is SQL or SQL Server.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos let me read about text qualifiers.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so if I add select "Phone_Num" from ----- 

when I export it the phone_num column is treated as text?

Comment: No. How do you export the file? The field/row delimiters, text qualifiers are all parameters of whatever method you use to generate a CSV file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 

CREATE TABLE "__datasetDownload"."a19fbcb4-0b86-4efd-9e90-a7a80f995b21" STORE AS (type => 'text', fieldDelimiter => ',', lineDelimiter => '
') WITH SINGLE WRITER AS SELECT * FROM ( SQL QUERY what i write)

this is what's happening

Comment: If you want to remove a char from a column you can simply [replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with Nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of opening the .csv file in Excel, use Excel to import the file.    Go to the "Data" ribbon and click the "From Text/CSV" button.  Select the file you exported, click the "Load" button and it should import the data from the CSV file with the phone # intact.  I ran a test on a .csv file that has phone #s in it and it worked like a charm.

Comment: On Excel 2010: 
1. Data > From Text > Choose .csv file
2. Original Data type - preview showed comma separated - chose Delimited.
3. Delimiters - Comma
4. Column data format - choose each column to show numbers as a string in and pick 'Text' radio button
5. Finish